# Run a PRAGMA command in WebSQL

Tags: html, local-storage, offline, web-sql

Is there any way to run a PRAGMA command from WebSQL? PRAGMA is defined in the SQLite documentation, but doesn't seem to work in WebSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not run any PRAGMA commands in webkit websql. As this is the core of the implementation base we can safely assume that this feature is unavailable for HTML5 applications.

Comment: not being able to use `PRAGMA table_info` is really *really* annoying.